# How to access elements of an array of function pointers using another pointer and in turn call one of the functions?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I declare an array of function pointers as follows:

`typedef void (*ptr[4])( int a,  int b)={fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4};`

Now i declare,

`ptr *ptr_to_fn_arr;`

The question is, how do I call any of the functions( fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4) using the pointer variable `ptr_to_fn_arr`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A typedef should not contain an assignment. Please provide samples that actually are valid code. And in general please provide a complete sample of your code

Comment: I agree with @Gerhardh-- to solve your problem, you should separate your typedef with your array allocation. Then you can simply index into the array to access the pointer to your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be easier to do this if we have the typedef be to the function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(int, int);
```

Now `fptr` is a typedef for "pointer to function accepting two ints and returning void".

So declaring the array is simple:

```
fptr fn_arr[4] = {fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4};
```

And declaring the pointer is simple:

```
fptr *ptr_to_fn_arr = fn_arr;
```

But now how do we call the functions?

`fn_arr` is an array of function pointers, so `fn_arr[i]` is a function pointer.

`ptr_to_fn_arr` is a pointer to a function pointers, so `*ptr_to_fn_arr` is a function pointer.  So is `ptr_to_fn_arr[i]`.  (The analogies here to more "ordinary" arrays and pointers should be obvious.)

So the strictly-interpreted way to call via ptr_to_fn_arr would be

```
(*(*ptr_to_fn_arr))(1, 2)
```

or

```
(*ptr_to_fn_arr[i])(3, 4)
```

But since the only thing you can do with a function pointer is call the pointed-to function, you don't actually *need* the explicit `*`, so both of these would work, too:

```
(*ptr_to_fn_arr)(1, 2)
```

or

```
ptr_to_fn_arr[i](3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` is used to create an alias name for other data type and you cannot initialize a type.
So, this is wrong:

```
typedef void (*ptr[4])( int a,  int b)={fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4};
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead you should do:

```
typedef void (*ptr[4])( int a,  int b);
```

This will creates `ptr` as a *type* for array of `4` function pointers that takes two `int` type as argument and does not return any value.

Now using this alias name `ptr` you can create variable of its type, like this:

```
ptr x = {fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4};
```

This will initialize variable `x` which is an array of `4` function pointers of type `ptr`.

You can call it like this:

```
x[0](1, 2); // this is equivalent to fn1(1, 2)
x[1](1, 2); // this is equivalent to fn2(1, 2)
....
.... and so on.
```

But the statement

```
ptr x = ...
```

Just by looking at it, it doesn't seems that `x` is an array until you look into the `ptr` typedef.
So, for better readability you can do:

```
typedef void (*ptr)( int a,  int b);
```

This will creates `ptr` as a *type* for function pointer that takes two `int` type as argument and does not return any value.

Now to create the array of `4` function pointers of type `ptr`, you can do:

```
ptr x[4] = {fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4};
```

Call it in similar way:

```
x[2](1, 2); // this is equivalent to fn3(1, 2)
```